# lampp server didn't start in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lampp

It shows server already running when i start the lampp through terminal.

It won't stop while i'm stop the lampp. shows the error like this..

```
sudo ./lampp stop
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 5.6.24-1...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
fail.
kill returned 2.
```

I don't know how to solve solve this issue help me to solve this

This is my error log and caught SIGTERM, shutting down error

```
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:23.021380 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1325] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:23.039622 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1325] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:23.039704 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1325] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:23.075693 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1329] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:24.001180 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1329] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:24.001214 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1329] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:24.001272 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1329] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:24.352570 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1329] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 23 09:38:24.352600 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1329] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:14.005811 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1354] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:14.024055 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1354] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:14.024133 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1354] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:14.059490 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1355] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:15.001101 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1355] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:15.001134 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1355] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:15.001197 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1355] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:15.143282 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1355] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 23 09:43:15.143310 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1355] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:40.011944 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1401] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:40.030140 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1401] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:40.030206 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 1401] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:40.065942 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1402] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:41.001331 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1402] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:41.001362 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1402] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:41.001419 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1402] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:41.140999 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1402] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.24 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 23 09:46:41.141027 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1402] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Wed Nov 23 09:47:23.193674 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1402] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably that apache was already started.

Try:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo ./lampp start
```

Comment: apache server, proFTPD starts after reinstalliing lampp. But mysql is not working. replies already running message. Checked and deleted all mysql components in my system. But still shows already running. WEIRD!